# Number of ways to color the vertex of a cube

Tags: combinatorics

Im thinking of a problem on coloring.

Given a cube, divide the cube into 8 unified area, Color the 8 area with 4 color. Givien constraints are

1. You can use repeated color.
2. If one coloring is the same as the other when rotated or reflected, it is consdered the same

What is the number of ways to color the cube

I figured this is essentially the same as coloring the vertex of a cube with the same constraints

One way i thought of is to color the vertex of two rectangle, postion the two such that the vertices line up in a space, so that will be 3!3!

But im quite sure that this does not count all the numbers of coloring.

I did not saw this on book, rather thought of it while walking, so if the answer to this question is trival will there be any resource to further extend the problem.

Comment: This is a standard exercise in using Burnside's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma